# WP_Query вместо шорткода

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Подскажите, как заменить нижеприведённый код вызова шорткода на аналогичный код, в котором используется WP_Query? Сам цикл я смогу построить на основе полученных данных из бд. Но как задать правильно запрос в базу данных, чтобы выбрать товары из категории sale_products или товары из product_category?

```
echo do_shortcode('[product_category category="computers"]');
или 
echo do_shortcode('[sale_products per_page="12"]');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Цикл, в общем-то обычный WordPress, с учетом того, что тип поста - `products`, и не категории, а таксономии. Свойства товара (например, цена распродажи) содержатся в мета-полях.

Для теста создана пустая страница, использующая файл шаблона. В файле шаблона:

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: woo-test-632707
*/

echo '<h2>Товары категории "Фильмы"</h2>';
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'product_cat' => 'фильмы',
    'posts_per_page' => -1
);

$wc_query = new WP_Query($args);

if ($wc_query->have_posts()) {
    while ($wc_query->have_posts()) {
        $wc_query->the_post();
        ?>

        <p><?php the_title(); ?></p>

        <?php
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
}
else {
    ?>
    <p><?php echo 'No Products'; ?></p>
    <?php
}

echo '<h2>Товары на распродаже</h2>';
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'meta_key' => '_sale_price',
    'meta_value' => '0',
    'meta_compare' => '>=',
    'posts_per_page' => 12
);

$wc_query = new WP_Query($args);

if ($wc_query->have_posts()) {
    while ($wc_query->have_posts()) {
        $wc_query->the_post();
        ?>

        <p><?php the_title(); ?></p>

        <?php
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
}
else {
    ?>
    <p><?php echo 'No Products'; ?></p>
    <?php
}

?>
```

Результат [здесь](http://test.kagg.eu/so632707/).